# Serve static resources from within a compressed file using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to serve static resources from within a compressed file using Spring MVC? Something like [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-static-zip).

I have some data packaged into individual JSON files (e.g. 123.json, 1634.json, etc.) and and currently serving them via

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

The files are under `.../resources/dataFiles/`. So a user can go to `http://mywebsite.com/resources/dataFiles/123.json` to retrieve the data for entity 123.

However, I have ~10,000 JSON files. It would be great if I could compress them under one file (`.../resources/dataFiles/entities.zip`) and tell Spring to serve the individual JSON files from within the compressed file.

So the user would still go to `http://mywebsite.com/resources/dataFiles/123.json` but the only file under `.../resources/dataFiles/` is entities.zip.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0 if this question is outside the scope of the MVC framework.

Comment: So you want Spring to unzip the `entities.zip`, get the entry for your specific file and send that?

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're asking. There is no `123.json` in `entities.zip`. There's an _entry_ for `123.json` but that entry only makes sense as part of the whole `.zip` file. You can always compress the `123.json` by itself.

Comment: Sorry @SotiriosDelimanolis, I tried to clarify a bit more in my edits, but your first comment is correct. I want to zip up all 10,000 files and place them under one compressed archive, which Spring will then treat as a folder so that individual files could be served. The module I link to in the question does exactly this (but I'm not using node).

Comment: I see. Spring doesn't have anything like that built-in. I don't know that it will necessarily be faster either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a Spring out-of-the-box component that does that, but you can create an independent Servlet to handle the incoming requests for static resources, then this servlet would parse the file name, and dynamically read from the zipped file the correct Zip Entry and return the content to the OutputStream of the Response. Take a look at:

[sample code](https://community.oracle.com/message/8676580)